# What is the GLib-CRITICAL in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I typed `firefox -v` in my console. The output was

```
firefox -v

(process:5516): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Mozilla Firefox 33.0
```

What is that failed assertion? Something serious?

Comment: Not if Firefox continues to work as expected.